# MySQL - Show Occurrences (Count) in a SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, count

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT
  orders.ord_Id,
  orders.ord_Email,
  products.pdt_Name
FROM
  orders, products
WHERE
  orders.ord_ProdId = products.pdt_Id
ORDER BY
 ord_Id;
```

And here is a sample result:

```
ord_Id  ord_Email          pdt_Name
1       email@test1.com    Product1
2       email@test1.com    Product2
3       email@test2.com    Product2
4       email@test1.com    Product1
5       email@test2.com    Product2
6       email@test3.com    Product2
```

I need to add an extra column that shows the occurrences of same e-mails in the list. Something like this:

```
ord_Id  ord_Email        Count  pdt_Name
1       email@test1.com  3      Product1
2       email@test1.com  3      Product2
3       email@test2.com  2      Product2
4       email@test1.com  3      Product1
5       email@test2.com  2      Product2
6       email@test3.com  1      Product2
```

I already tryied using COUNT(DISTINCT(ord_Email)) and insert a SELECT inside this SELECT, but had no sucess.

PS. I need the entire list appears in the result.

Please, can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  or.ord_email,
        o.ord_id,
        cnt,
        p.pdt_name
FROM    (
        SELECT  ord_email, COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM    orders
        GROUP BY
                ord_email
        ) oe
JOIN    orders o
ON      o.ord_email = oe.ord_email
JOIN    products p
ON      p.pdt_id = o.ord_prodid
```

Create an index on `orders (ord_email)` for this to work fast.

Comment: Hi @Quassnoi. Thank you! I am newbie on SQL, and try to understand the lines "o.ord_Id" and "orders o"...

Answer (score 0):

Please read up on GROUP BY (in your case ord_Email) - that is the way to combine - then the COUNT will yield the occurences you're after. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @user3741598! Thank you! Well, I need the entire list appears, and if I use GROUP BY, the result will be grouped. Am I wrong? You mean something like this? SELECT orders.ord_Id, orders.ord_Email, products.pdt_Name, COUNT(ord_Email) AS NEmails FROM orders, products WHERE orders.ord_ProdId = products.pdt_Id GROUP BY ord_Email ORDER BY ord_Id;